# Correct HTML syntax in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, simplecart

My problem is that I don't know the correct syntax for implementing html in a javascript snippet.

I'm using simplecart.js and I would like to add a custom cart column with the color of one item in it, but I'm stuck with this since one hour.

```
{
    view: function (item, column) {
        "<div id='couleur'>
        <div style='background-color:'"
        return item.get('color')"'></div>
    </div>"
    },
    label: "Couleur"
},
```

Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow. A return statement in between string literals? What result were you expecting? String formation and concatenation is pretty basic. Maybe a read through a basic JavaScript tutorial is in order?

Comment: ...and we don't know what `item` is, so we can't help much with that. Maybe it's correct. Can't tell.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm not even a beginner in js, so I probably asked a question which could appear silly to you.
I'll take the time to read some basic rules in js, but for now, I have to hurry and I'm stuck at this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have line breaks in a string, you have nested double quotes, snd you have a function call that makes no sense.

```
view: function (item, column) {
    var str = "<div id='couleur'>" +
              "<div style='background-color:" + item.get('color') + "'></div>" +
              "</div>";
    return str;
}
```

Most people would use more of a templating type of architecture.

```
view: function (item, column) {
    var str = "<div id='couleur'><div style='background-color:{color}'></div></div>";
    return str.replace("{color}", item.get('color'));
}
```

Comment: It's working! 
No line breaks in a js code - I got it.
Thanks a lot!